# iOS12 `connectPeripheral: options:` slower than iOS11

Tags: core-bluetooth, ios12

I try connect a discovered peripheral by `connectPeripheral: options:`(btw:options is nil), but it needs 10s+ on iOS12 device.
iOS11 device just need 2-5s.

Comment: Did you have a question? This seems more like a statement.

Comment: oh I mean why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I find the cause of the phenomenon.

it will seriously affect the performance of `connectPeripheral: options:`if you invoke `stopScan` immediately after scan peripheral on iOS12.